# "Error waiting for internet gateway to detach" when destroying EKS cluster with Terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, subnet

I deploy the cluster like this:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

data "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = module.eks.cluster_id
}

data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "cluster" {
  name = module.eks.cluster_id
}

variable "cluster_name" {
  default = "my-cluster"
}

variable "instance_type" {
  default = "t2.large"
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.certificate_authority.0.data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.cluster.token
  load_config_file       = false
  version                = "~> 1.11"
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
}


module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "3.0.0"

  name                 = "k8s-${var.cluster_name}-vpc"
  cidr                 = "172.16.0.0/16"
  azs                  = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
  private_subnets      = ["172.16.1.0/24", "172.16.2.0/24", "172.16.3.0/24"]
  public_subnets       = ["172.16.4.0/24", "172.16.5.0/24", "172.16.6.0/24"]
  enable_nat_gateway   = true
  single_nat_gateway   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  public_subnet_tags = {
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.cluster_name}" = "shared"
    "kubernetes.io/role/elb"                    = "1"
  }

  private_subnet_tags = {
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.cluster_name}" = "shared"
    "kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb"           = "1"
  }
}

module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "12.2.0"

  cluster_name    = "${var.cluster_name}"
  cluster_version = "1.18"
  subnets         = module.vpc.private_subnets

  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id

  worker_groups = [
   {
     name                          = "worker-group-1"
     instance_type                 = "t3.small"
     additional_userdata           = "echo foo bar"
     asg_desired_capacity          = 2
     #additional_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.worker_group_mgmt_one.id]
   },
   {
     name                          = "worker-group-2"
     instance_type                 = "t3.small"
     additional_userdata           = "echo foo bar"
     #additional_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.worker_group_mgmt_two.id]
     asg_desired_capacity          = 1
   },
  ]
  

  write_kubeconfig   = true
  config_output_path = "./"

  workers_additional_policies = [aws_iam_policy.worker_policy.arn]
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "worker_policy" {
  name        = "worker-policy-${var.cluster_name}"
  description = "Worker policy for the ALB Ingress"

  policy = file("iam-policy.json")
}
```

I also deploy a Nginx Ingress controller via Helm.

The deployment runs perfectly but get this error when I run `terraform destroy`:

```
module.dev_cluster.module.vpc.aws_subnet.public[1]: Still destroying... [id=subnet-0bfa486ee8fd490fc, 19m40s elapsed]
module.dev_cluster.module.vpc.aws_subnet.public[1]: Still destroying... [id=subnet-0bfa486ee8fd490fc, 19m50s elapsed]
module.dev_cluster.module.vpc.aws_subnet.public[0]: Still destroying... [id=subnet-00179aea4aeb2711e, 19m50s elapsed]
module.dev_cluster.module.vpc.aws_subnet.public[0]: Still destroying... [id=subnet-00179aea4aeb2711e, 20m0s elapsed]
module.dev_cluster.module.vpc.aws_subnet.public[1]: Still destroying... [id=subnet-0bfa486ee8fd490fc, 20m0s elapsed]

Error: Error waiting for internet gateway (igw-0ede95704f16bf459) to detach: timeout while waiting for state to become 'detached' (last state: 'detaching', timeout: 15m0s)

Error: error deleting subnet (subnet-00179aea4aeb2711e): timeout while waiting for state to become 'destroyed' (last state: 'pending', timeout: 20m0s)

Error: Unauthorized

Error: error deleting subnet (subnet-0bfa486ee8fd490fc): timeout while waiting for state to become 'destroyed' (last state: 'pending', timeout: 20m0s)
```

I have the feeling that I lack a dependency somewhere to let Terraform have the rights to delete everything until the end of the deletion but I don't see where.

I would like to be able to completely destroy my cluster via the `terraform destroy` command without having to manually delete resources via the AWS console.

**Edit:** The `terraform destroy` command works fine if I don't install the NGINX Ingress controller. It fails only after I install my Ingress like this: `helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx`. So Terraform is not aware of this installation.

Is it possible to fix this by adding a policy related to the Ingress ?

**Edit:** Fixed by deploying the Ingress via Terraform instead of by command line:

```
provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.endpoint
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.certificate_authority.0.data)
    token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.cluster.token
    load_config_file       = false
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "ingress-nginx" {
  name       = "ingress-nginx"
  repository = "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/"
  chart      = "ingress-nginx"
}
```

Comment: Can you also share the configuration of the nginx-ingress helm chart? I recently had a similar problem in Azure using the nginx ingress. The problem was related to the load balancer configuration and the fact, that the nginx ingress actually creates resources in the subnet terraform later wants to destroy. If you then just tear down the cluster without properly uninstalling  the nginx ingress first, the stuff just gets left behind.

Comment: I resolved the issue by deploying the ingress via Terraform aswell (see code in the edit). I can now deploy the ingress resource and deployments/services with yaml files and am still able to `terraform destroy` the cluster.

Comment: I would not neccessarily recommend doing the helm deployment and cluster provisioning during the same terraform apply step. It can introduce some unwanted side effects due to the dependency of the provider configuration on the cluster eks resource. You can read more about that in the official docs for the k8s provider: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs#stacking-with-managed-kubernetes-cluster-resources